# Add a new attribute to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `JSON` object of the following format

```
[{"field1":1,"field2":"A","field3":"B"},
{"field1":2,"field2":"B","field3":"C"},
{......},
{......},
]
```

I need to add a new attribute to each row based on some calculations.

Expected result

```
[{"field1":1,"field2":"A","field3":"B","field4"="generatedVal1"},
    {"field1":2,"field2":"B","field3":"C","field4"="generatedVal2"},
    {......},
    {......},
    ]
```

How can I achieve this using `javascript`?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. I give it about 99% odds you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```
[
  {"field1":1,"field2":"A","field3":"B"},
  {"field1":2,"field2":"B","field3":"C"}
]
.forEach(obj => {
  obj.field4 = 'Something'
})
```

Sidenote on terminology: you don't have any JSON, you have javascript array (object). JSON is a string representation of this object, but in your question you are talking about object itself.